# Why does my MacBook Pro (2011) lose Wi-Fi connection when connected to Thunderbolt Display?

Tags: macbook-pro, wifi, thunderbolt, thunderbolt-display

My MacBook Pro (2011) loses Wi-Fi connection when connected to a Thunderbolt display. This problem developed a few months ago -- prior to this, I never had any problems with Wi-Fi. Now, when I connect my MacBook Pro via Thunderbolt and go into full screen mode, the Wi-Fi won't work.

I've already gone into Network preferences and done diagnostics. Wi-Fi goes in and out -- sometimes a diagnostic will report that Wi-Fi is connected, but it quickly loses the connection.

There has been no changes to my internet provider or its service. The Thunderbolt display remains in the same position it has for years.

Comment: macOS version?  Was there an OS update/upgrade of any kind?  Just to clarify, the problem only manifests when going into *full screen mode*; otherwise works fine?  Have you tried in Safe  mode to see if the problem persists?

Comment: I'm wondering if it thinks the display is providing a wi-fi card. Have you checked System Report while this is happening to see if it's seeing anything?

Comment: macOS is El Capitan - 10.11.6. And yes -- in full screen mode. When I simply have my mac connected to the monitor as an additional screen, the wifi works fine. I tried in safe mode, and the problem persists. I checked the System Report as well -- the wifi report under networks seemed the same as when the wifi is working properly. I do notice that when the monitor is in full screen mode, the amount of wifi networks that it detects reduces drastically. Internet speed goes from 20mbs (normal) to .5mbs. Thanks in advance!